# Why is an interval used to define homotopy, categorically speaking?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

It seems that one could define homotopy *almost* all in category theory as follows:

> Let $T$ be a terminal object and $I$ be some object. Let $i_0,i_1:T\rightarrow I$ be two maps. Suppose that $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are two morphisms. Let $\pi:X\times T\rightarrow X$ be the appropriate projection map. Call $X$ and $Y$ homotopic if there is a morphism $h:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ such that $$h\circ (\operatorname{id}_X\times i_0)=f\circ \pi$$
>   $$h\circ (\operatorname{id}_X\times i_1)=g\circ \pi$$

One can see that if we choose $I$ to be the unit interval, and $i_0$ and $i_1$ to be the maps sending a single point to either end of the interval, then this is the usual notion of homotopy equivalence.

However, I find myself bothered by the apparent necessity to choose $I$ and the maps $i_0$ and $i_1$. I seem to recall that I've read that there is some category theoretic property that identifies the interval as the appropriate choice for homotopy, but I cannot seem to find any (accessible) reference that makes such a construction.

Why is the interval used as $I$ in this construction?

My primary motivation for asking this is that I am interested in notions that look very similar to homotopy and which may be defined in other categories using appropriate choices of $I$ and $i_0$ and $i_1$ - but I'd like to know if there is some deeper property I ought to be looking for when making such a choice.

Comment: It sounds like you've (re)discovered the notion of an [interval object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+object) in a category.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900156/why-are-homotopies-defined-by-real-intervals?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interval is the terminal space with two distinguished points ($0$ and $1$) and a map to its wedge product with itself. The first structure, which you mentioned, says that maps out of $X\times I$ are some kind of homotopies, while the second says that homotopies may be composed. Notice that this second property is very uncommon in more abstract settings, for instance in model categories in which not every object is fibrant. See the first answer here for more: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92206/what-properties-make-0-1-a-good-candidate-for-defining-fundamental-groups

Comment: Should the first sentence say "with two base points..."?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Originally the post read "The interval is the terminal space with two point and a map to its wedge product with itself." Someone edited it.