# Is "generalized" singular homology/cohomology a thing? If not, why not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory, homological-algebra, universal-algebra

From what I understand, the singular homology groups of a topological space are defined like so:

> **Topological Particulars.** There's a covariant functor $F : \mathbb{\Delta} \rightarrow \mathbf{Top}$ that assigns to each natural number $n$ the corresponding $n$-simplex. This yields a functor $$\mathbf{Top}(F-,-) : \Delta^{op} \times \mathbf{Top} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}.$$ Hence to each topological space $X$, we can assign a simplicial set $\mathbf{Top}(F-,X) : \Delta^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}.$
>
> **General nonsense.** We observe that every simplicial set induces a simplicial abelian group; that every simplicial abelian group induces a chain complex; and that chain complexes have homology and cohomology groups. Ergo, simplicial sets have homology/cohomology groups.

Putting these together, we may speak of the homology and cohomology groups of a topological space $X$. However, the topological particulars don't seem too important. In fact, for any category $\mathbf{C}$ and any functor $F : \Delta \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$, there's a simplicial set $\mathbf{C}(F-,X)$ attached to each $X \in \mathbf{C}$, and therefore $X$ has homology and cohomology.

For example, the underlying set functor $U : \mathbf{CMon} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ has a left-adjoint $F : \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{CMon}$. But since $\Delta \subseteq \mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{CMon} \subseteq \mathbf{Mon}$, this yields a functor $F : \Delta \rightarrow \mathbf{Mon}$. This should in turn allow us to attach homology and cohomology groups to each monoid $M$, by studying the simplicial set $\mathbf{Mon}(F-,M)$.

> **Question.** Is this a thing? If not, why not?

Comment: Not all such things will satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, yes, sure; and, the homotopy axiom doesn't even make sense at this level of generality. But, still, we can study these groups. Is there any reason not to?

Comment: It makes more sense for model categories.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'Is this a thing?' is really asking. I guess one of: Is it *possible*? Is it *interesting*? Is it *studied*? The first has an answer, so too the last but probably its more difficult. The second one for reasons which are themselves not very interesting, is more or less unanswerable.

Comment: @user259242, both, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer this. I'm going to upvote it, just because its more advanced (and therefore probably interesting) than a lot of other stuff on the front page.

Comment: @user259242 And therein lies your mistake.

Comment: @AlexYoucis That is a wildly opaque comment to make. Please use your words better, or stop being cryptic.

Comment: @user259242 OK. I was merely commenting on the fact that '...just because it's more advanced (and therefore probably interesting)...' can be a bad perspective. It was just a harmless jab, hopefully taken in good spirits :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis smiley faces defuses all (:

Comment: @user259242 Indeed they do. Cheers :) Hopefully this question gets answered.

Comment: Does $\Delta$ refer here to a simplex or the set of all simplices? Is the question similar to "why consider only continuous maps from n-simplices, and not also continuous maps from more general topological spaces"? For the record I don't know the answer, that's just a question I realized I have about singular homology, and I'm not sure if your question is the same.

Comment: @William The $\Delta$ refers to the [simplicial category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+category), typically. A simplicial set is the same thing as a functor $\Delta^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$. For your second question, you may be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1465472/10014) perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you have a cosimplicial object $F^\bullet \in \mathsf{cC}$ (AKA a functor $F : \Delta \to \mathsf{C}$), and an object $X \in \mathsf{C}$; and you're considering the simplicial set $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(F^\bullet, X) \in \mathsf{sSet}$. Sure, people use constructions like this from time to time, it's a very general construction... But since it's so general it's hard to get more specific than that. It occurs in tons of different settings.

I don't think it's really fair to call that "the homology of $X$", either; it heavily depends on what $F^\bullet$ is. For example when you have a category tensored over $\mathsf{sSet}$, given two objects $X$ and $Y$, you can build the mapping space
$$\operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{C}}(X,Y) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X \otimes \Delta^\bullet, Y) \in \mathsf{sSet}$$
which is used very, very often, satisfying among other things $\pi_0 \operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{C}}(X,Y) = [X,Y]$ is the set of homotopy classes of map $X \to Y$.

Even more specifically the singular simplicial set $S_\bullet(X)$ is given by $\operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Top}}(*, X)$ (where $\mathsf{Top}$ is tensored over simplicial sets in the standard fashion). So homology is really a special case of a special case.

What you're considering is very general. Homology is interesting because it satisfies things like the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms, we have theorems like the UCT, Künneth's theorem... You can prove a great deal about homology using the setting you're considering (for example $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(F^\bullet, X \times Y) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(F^\bullet, X) \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(F^\bullet, Y)$ is obvious, and then you have the Eilenberg–Zilber theorem and finally Künneth's formula), but many other properties heavily depend on the specific $F^\bullet = |\Delta^\bullet|$ used.